# Tensorflow MapDataset iterator fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to implement the method suggested by the tensorflow documentation over here (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) to load images from local directory as a tensorflow dataset. Especially I am interested in loading using tf.data as a tf.data.Dataset object as it is suggested that the performance is better that way. I pretty much took the exact code from the documentation page and also made sure that the tensorflow version matches to the one in the documentation

The problem happens when I try to iterate over the MapDataset object using take().

```
import os
import sys
import pathlib

import IPython.display as display
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(3670/BATCH_SIZE)
CLASS_NAMES = None

#https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

def get_label(file_path):
    # convert the path to a list of path components
    #parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, result_type = 'RaggedTensor')
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path)

    # The second to last is the class-directory
    return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES

def decode_img(img):
    # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)

    # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)

    # resize the image to the desired size.
    return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT])

def process_path(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)

    # load the raw data from the file as a string
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)

    return img, label

def test():

    data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
                                         fname='flower_photos', untar=True)

    data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

    global CLASS_NAMES
    CLASS_NAMES = np.array([item.name for item in data_dir.glob('*') if item.name != "LICENSE.txt"])

    list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'))

    labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path)
    print('type: ', type(labeled_ds))

    for image, label in labeled_ds.take(1):
        print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
        print("Label: ", label.numpy())

def main():
    test()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following error and have no idea how to go about resolving this

```
2020-04-17 09:47:53.816123: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1655] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:108 : Invalid argument: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2020-04-17 09:47:53.820082: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1655] OP_REQUIRES failed at iterator_ops.cc:941 : Invalid argument: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
         [[{{node strided_slice}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\context.py", line 1897, in execution_mode
    yield
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 659, in _next_internal
    output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2478, in iterator_get_next_sync
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 6606, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
         [[{{node strided_slice}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\img_sub_model.py", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\img_sub_model.py", line 145, in main
    test()
  File ".\img_sub_model.py", line 136, in test
    for image, label in labeled_ds.take(1):
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 630, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 674, in next
    return self._next_internal()
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 665, in _next_internal
    return structure.from_compatible_tensor_list(self._element_spec, ret)
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\context.py", line 1900, in execution_mode
    executor_new.wait()
  File "C:\Users\VVJ3281\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\executor.py", line 67, in wait
    pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_ExecutorWaitForAllPendingNodes(self._handle)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: slice index -1 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
         [[{{node strided_slice}}]]
```

By some random coincidence I found that when CLASS_NAMES is set to None, the code runs and the lebel object of labeled_ds has a value 'False'

See output below

```
type:  <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset'>
Image shape:  (224, 224, 3)
Label:  False
```

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs because `get_label` performs an out-of-bounds list access

```
def get_label(file_path):
    # convert the path to a list of path components
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path)

    # The second to last is the class-directory
    return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES
```

`parts` has size `1`. This is because `tf.strings.split` will split by whitespace unless you specify what delimiter to use. To split into path components, it should be `parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, "/")`

To debug this sort of issue, you can add `tf.print` statements to your functions, e.g.

```
def get_label(file_path):
    # convert the path to a list of path components
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path)

    # The second to last is the class-directory
    tf.print(file_path)
    tf.print(len(parts))
    return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES
```